# How can i extract substring from the string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String `xxxxxxxxsrc="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg"xxxxxxxx` Now, I want to extract substrings `slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg` & `Note.jpg` from the String in to variables `i.e. temp1 & temp2.`

How can I do that using regex in Java?

> Note: 63338424306 could be any random no. & Note.jpg could be anything
>   like Note.png or abc.jpg or xxxx.yyy etc.

Please help me to extract these two strings using regex.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: As of now i am not sure about how to extract substrings using regex but this is the requirement. So, i am asking for help. If you can help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: Showing us what you tried, encourages and helps people to help you back. You should share whatever code/regex you have written, doesn't matter partially or totally broken.

Comment: i understand but for now i have to learn from scratch to try that will consume lot of time. So, i am seeking help and learn asap ;)

Comment: It seems your string is URL and you want to grab filename with any extension. One of the way to achieve it as `(\w+\.)+\w+$`

Comment: @Vebbie: Thank you for your answer ;) Can you please help me with Java code as i am not so sure about regex. As the requirement is to extract two substrings in to temp variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look behind to get file name

```
((?:.(?<!/))+)\"
```

and below regex to get full path

```
/(.*)\"
```

Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(.*)\"");
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("((?:.(?<!/))+)\"");
    String matchString = "/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg\"xxxxxxxx";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(matchString);
    String fullString = "";
    while (matcher.find()) {
        fullString = matcher.group(1);
    }
    matcher = pattern1.matcher(matchString);
    String fileName = "";
    while (matcher.find()) {
        fileName = matcher.group(1);
    }

    System.out.println(fullString + " " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: Hey Ashish - Thank you for your answer ;) but it does not fulfill my requirement. When i run your code i am getting Note.jpg as the output but i want two outputs i.e. 'slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg' & 'Note.jpg' from the String xxxxxxxxsrc="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg"xxxxxxxx.

Comment: @Ajay - You will have to use two regex here to achieve this. I have updated my answer. Have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment taking the string as declared below in my code:

Please clarify if your input string is not like this or I'm missing something.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "xxxxxxxxsrc=\"/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg\"xxxxxxxx";
    String url = null;

    // The below pattern will grab string between quotes
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        url = m.group(1);
    }

    // and this will grab filename from the path(url)
    p = Pattern.compile("(?:.(?<!/))+$");
    m = p.matcher(url);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```